# Mysql retrieve polygon data

Tags: php, mysql, geospatial, polygon

i have been developing a site that stores spatial data in mysql database, like that of buildings, gardens, etc. in the form of polygons (latitudes and longitudes).

I want to know how to retrieve polygon data in mysql.

I have seen this sample query to insert a polygon data:
http://amper.110mb.com/SPAT/mysql_initgeometry2.htm

But now i want to know how to retrieve data from the table, based on certain constraints like:

`"where latitude < 9.33 and longitude > 22.4"`
Also how do i find whether a point lies inside or outside of a polygon

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a page with lots of examples: http://howto-use-mysql-spatial-ext.blogspot.com/

This is one of the examples to retrieve rows which points intersect with a specified bounding box:

```
SET @bbox = 'POLYGON((0 0, 10 0, 10 10, 0 10, 0 0))'; 
SELECT name, AsText(location) FROM Points
    WHERE Intersects( location, GeomFromText(@bbox) );
```

The [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/functions-that-test-spatial-relationships-between-geometries.html) says these spatial functions also work with geometries (Looks like a Point is also a Geometry). So you can check if the geometry in the database intersects with the one you specify in the select statement.

Comment: So do i need to insert a point with a latitude and longitude in the Points table, and use it to search within a polygon?

Comment: In this example "location" is of type "Point", yes. A "point" contains the horizontal and vertical position. See the linked example page to see how this example table is created and filled. But it should also work with "Geometry" type. I have extended the answer to cover this.

Comment: I tried the process mentioned in that page, but i get no rows for the query above. Is it because that the point's coordinates (31.5 42.2) are more than the polygon dimension (10)? But even if i increased the polygon's dimensions to 50, i am not getting any rows

Comment: The polygon does not intersect with 31.5,42.2 because it defines a rectangle from 0,0 up to 10,10. But it should intersect your point with a polygon dimension of 50. Did you use (0 0, 50 0, 50 50, 0 50, 0 0) to test? Maybe you can give a full example with example table content, the SQL statement you used and the result you got and which one you expected?

Comment: Yes kayahr, i used (0 0, 50 0, 50 50, 0 50, 0 0) to test. I will surely explain what i did.

Comment: First i created Points table: create table Points (name VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY, location Point NOT NULL, description VARCHAR(200), SPATIAL INDEX(location) ) ENGINE=MYISAM. Then i inserted a row: INSERT INTO Points (name, location) VALUES ( 'point1' , GeomFromText( ' POINT(31.5 42.2) ' ) ); Then i wrote this query:  SET @bbox = 'POLYGON((0 0, 50 0, 50 50, 0 50, 0 0))'; SELECT name, AsText(location) FROM Points
    WHERE Intersects( location, GeomFromText(@bbox) );
But i get 0 rows.

Comment: I executed exactly your statements and it returns the point. When I change the polygon to dimension 10x10 then it doesn't return the point. Looks correct to me. Maybe you are using transactions and the insert is not committed before you execute your select?

Comment: Iam using MyISAM engine in table creation above. But i cant understand why i am not able to get proper results.

Comment: Anyways, i found a better strategy here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5105035/get-polygon-points-mysql :)