# Get polygon points mysql

Tags: php, mysql, polygon

i have created a table in mysql to store polygon data:

```
CREATE TABLE geom (g GEOMETRY);
```

And i inserted a polygon into it, using the following syntax:

```
INSERT INTO geom (g)
VALUES(PolygonFromText('POLYGON((
9.190586853 45.464518970,
9.190602686 45.463993916,
9.191572471 45.464001929,
9.191613325 45.463884676,
9.192136130 45.463880767,
9.192111509 45.464095594,
9.192427961 45.464117804,
9.192417811 45.464112862,
9.192509035 45.464225851,
9.192493139 45.464371079,
9.192448471 45.464439002,
9.192387444 45.464477861,
9.192051402 45.464483037,
9.192012814 45.464643592,
9.191640825 45.464647090,
9.191622331 45.464506215,
9.190586853 45.464518970))')
);
```

Now how can i get back the vertices (points) of this polygon in mysql? Why i am asking means, later i want to find whether a point is inside a polygon. And to achieve this, i hope i need the polygon vertices.

Comment: did u mean ExteriorRing+InteriorRing http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/geometry-property-functions.html#function_exteriorring

Comment: No, after inserting the polygon, i dont know its vertices anymore, as iam not storing those vertices in database. Now how can i get back these vertices, (in WKT format) if at all possible?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you want the WKT back: `SELECT AsText(g) FROM geom;`

Comment: Thanks, but i get the result as BLOB type.. how to fetch vertices from this?

Comment: You should get WKT in text format, see http://pastebin.com/H8ztP2pK, which can be easily parsed for the points. If not, I'm curious which version you use.

Comment: Thanks Wrikken, that helped me a lot. You rock!

Comment: @Wrikken: can you please check the link which you shared ? it seems broken. can you tell me answer again ?

Comment: @user2959196: the only thing that was there was a mysql cli history, showing how `asText()` worked. This did not change the answer itself. [It looked a lot like this](http://pastebin.com/KAHxQ0iy). This indeed means you have to parse that `POLYGON` (or whatever geometry) string yourself again in application code. There was no magic there getting the points in different rows or columns. Most languages would have some kind of WKT parser, be it in their core, modules, or in userland code.

Comment: `AsText()` and `AsWKT()` are deprecated as of MySQL 5.7.6 and will be removed in a future MySQL release. Use `ST_AsText()` and `ST_AsWKT()` instead. [MySQL Doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gis-format-conversion-functions.html)

Answer (score 5):

To answer your question, a great option would be to output the GeoJSON format.
See more here: (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-geojson-functions.html)

```
select ST_AsGeoJSON(g) from geom;
```

To help with your actual problem of selecting points in the bounding polygon: @jcorry has a great solution with `ST_Contains`

To further expand this out to select all `point`s from a `coordinates` table that the Polygon encapsulates, you can do something like:

```
select
ST_X(point) as x,
ST_Y(point) as y   
from coordinates
where ST_Contains(
    (select g from geom limit 1), 
    point
)
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to find whether a point is in a polygon, you don't need to derive the individual vertices to do that. There's a function in MySQL (5.6+) for this:

```
SELECT ST_Contains(PolygonFromText('POLYGON((
9.190586853 45.464518970,
9.190602686 45.463993916,
9.191572471 45.464001929,
9.191613325 45.463884676,
9.192136130 45.463880767,
9.192111509 45.464095594,
9.192427961 45.464117804,
9.192417811 45.464112862,
9.192509035 45.464225851,
9.192493139 45.464371079,
9.192448471 45.464439002,
9.192387444 45.464477861,
9.192051402 45.464483037,
9.192012814 45.464643592,
9.191640825 45.464647090,
9.191622331 45.464506215,
9.190586853 45.464518970))'), PointFromText("POINT(10 42)")
);
```