# BETWEEN not working properly

Tags: mysql, sql, geocoding

My table has latitude and longitude values stored as text. For a record whose lat and long values are:

```
+------+-------------------+--------------------+
| Name |        Lat        |        Long        |
+------+-------------------+--------------------+
| ABC  | 32.74943951828427 | -97.33141142455626 |
+------+-------------------+--------------------+
```

My SQL query is coming out like:

```
SELECT * FROM Incident I WHERE
(I.Lat BETWEEN '32.740446302225' AND '32.758432734343') 
AND 
(I.Long BETWEEN '-97.342104340547' AND '-97.320718508566')
LIMIT 5
```

But this is resulting in 0 rows being returned. The `"ABC"` record does exist in the table but I don't know why it isn't pulling it. Can strings not be compared as floating point numbers?

Comment: The bigger question is why you are using your latitude and longitude values in this way?  Typically, you would want to compute _distances_ from one point to `ABC` or other locations in your table.

Comment: And that can be done via SQL query?

Comment: Google "Haversine MySQL"

Comment: Maby you should use a [polygon search](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5101140/mysql-retrieve-polygon-data)

Comment: `x BETWEEN a AND b` means `a <= x AND x <= b`. But `'-97.342104340547' > '-97.320718508566'` (because the strings compares using the dictionary order) and this leads to searching `I.Lat` in an empty range. Obviously, it doesn't find any record.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That happens because you are using them as strings.

`BETWEEN` syntax is -> `value BETWEEN small_val AND big_val` , but since you are using them as strings  , `-97.34..` is bigger then `-97.32` and therefore it doesn't work.

Try:

```
(CAST(I.Lat as UNSIGNED) BETWEEN 32.740446302225 AND 32.758432734343) 
AND 
(CAST(I.Long as UNSIGNED) BETWEEN -97.342104340547 AND -97.320718508566)
```

Storing Numerical values in String type columns is wrong! I strongly recommend you change it to a Numerical type, as it should be .

Comment: I store them as strings, the datatype of `Lat` and `Long` columns is `varchar`

Comment: Why are you storing numerical data as varchar?

Comment: It's a legacy system and that is how it was created during the design phase. So changing the table column type might not be possible at this stage

Comment: @asprin As I said, if not - cast them. Anyways - I strongly recommend you store them as numbers, since that's what they are.

Comment: I removed the single quotes and it does seem to work. I thought it would give an error since `I.Lat` returns a string but we are comparing it with a number

Comment: Casting; that's what it's for! `:)`

Comment: @asprin The optimizer did its own cast. Try with casting, see edit .